# Lucene Indexes in Sitecore getting corrupted (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

We are having an issue with searching a Lucene Index in Sitecore. Everything works fine for a while, and then, after what appears to be a random amount of time, we start getting the following error on every single search against the index:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException 
Message: Non-negative number required. 
Parameter name: capacity Source: mscorlib 
  at System.Collections.Hashtable..ctor(Int32 capacity, Single loadFactor)
  at System.Collections.Hashtable.Clone() 
  at SupportClass.WeakHashTable.Clean() 
  at SupportClass.WeakHashTable.CleanIfNeeded() 
  at SupportClass.WeakHashTable.Add(Object key, Object value) 
  at Lucene.Net.Util.CloseableThreadLocal.Set(Object object) 
  at Lucene.Net.Index.TermInfosReader.GetThreadResources() 
  at Lucene.Net.Index.TermInfosReader.Get(Term term, Boolean useCache) 
  at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentReader.DocFreq(Term t) 
  at Lucene.Net.Index.DirectoryReader.DocFreq(Term t) 
  at Lucene.Net.Search.Similarity.IdfExplain(Term term, Searcher searcher)
  at Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery.CreateWeight(Searcher searcher) 
  at Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery.BooleanWeight..ctor(BooleanQuery enclosingInstance, Searcher searcher) 
  at Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery.CreateWeight(Searcher searcher) 
  at Lucene.Net.Search.Query.Weight(Searcher searcher) 
  at Lucene.Net.Search.Hits..ctor(Searcher s, Query q, Filter f, Sort o) 
  at Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher.Search(Query query, Sort sort) 
  at scSearchContrib.Searcher.QueryRunner.RunQuery(Query query, Boolean showAllVersions, String sortField, Boolean reverse, Int32 start, Int32 end) 
  at scSearchContrib.Searcher.QueryRunner.GetItems(IEnumerable`1 parameters, Boolean showAllVersions, String sortField, Boolean reverse, Int32 start, Int32 end) at
```

Looking at the .Net code and Lucene.Net code being called (via ILSpy), I can't see how this would actually happen. Calling .Clone() on a hashtable shouldn't allow a negative number for the hashtable capacity to be passed in.

This has happened several times, on multiple servers in our farm, and restarting IIS resolves the issue. This leads me to believe that there is some sort of in-memory corruption happening, but I'm not sure what would cause this or how to figure out what is going on.

Comment: whats the Lucene version used? Has it been modified by the product you use? If you can, post the code from the WeakHashtable Count property (the method should be overriden). If that code has been modified and somehow returns -1, the Clone() method from MS will generate that exception.

Comment: It is version 2.9.4 of Lucene and has not been updated at all. There is no code for WeakHashtable.Count because that property is not overridden and uses the base implementation from Hashtable.

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore support has a workaround for this for Sitecore 6.6.  There are apparently some nasty thread-safety issues with the WeakHashTable class used in Lucene.NET 2.9.4.  This issue is addressed in later versions of Lucene.NET and via the corresponding upgrades in Sitecore 7.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. We had this happening, and Sitecore Support did indeed have a hotfix ready to deploy :-)

Comment: For those looking for the fix, it's here - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/840772

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing number of worker threads for Sitecore by adding following setting to web.config

```
<setting name="MaxWorkerThreads" value="100"/>
```

Comment: Why would this do anything?

Comment: I had faced a similar issue with publishing, where publishing used to get stuck with an exception and I had to reset app pool every time and increasing MaxWorkerThreads fixed my issue